# Why is my embedded LucidChart throwing errors and 40k+ warnings?

Tags: html, iframe, embedding, lucidchart

I have 2 embedded Lucid Chart charts in my web page and they visually work just fine but when inspecting the page there is a set of warnings and errors. While the page is open the warnings will continually be thrown.

They also seem to change sometimes when the page is reloaded.

Errors:

```
GET https://static-assets.lucidchart.com/assets/20240127-001026-68ef2a8d/css/apps/chart/editor2/style.css.br
```

> net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
>
> This page failed to load a stylesheet from a URL.
> 2 requests
> 2 sources

After running for a few minutes

```
GET https://users.lucid.app/accounts/169061729/chart/subscription
```

> 404 (Not Found)
>
> Warnings:
>
> Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab.
>
> Deprecated feature used
>
> Cookies with the SameSite=None; Secure and not Partitioned attributes that operate in cross-site contexts are third-party cookies. In future Chrome versions, reading third-party cookies will be blocked. This behavior protects user data from cross-site tracking.
> Please refer to the article linked to learn more about preparing your site to avoid potential breakage.
> 20 cookies
> 534 requests

I'm unsure what else to add about the issue. They seem to be using a depreciated feature that causes all these other issues. Here is the html:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 480px; position: relative;">
    <iframe allowfullscreen frameborder="0" style="width:100%; height:100%" src="https://lucid.app/documents/embedded/5a54386f-f5ec-47b0-9b48-4d44c1a5eb91" id="f9-RemeU7pKR"></iframe>
</div>
```

And this is my site: https://pantheradigital.github.io/?projects=

Is this an issue I can fix or is it an issue with Lucid?

Can I do anything to remedy this?